# How can I get my desktop background back?

Tags: xfce

I've suddenly lost my desktop background in Xfce and I can't seem to work out why it's not displaying:

```
joe@Joe-Car-Laptop ~ $ xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -lv
/backdrop/screen0/monitor0/image-path  /usr/share/backgrounds/xfce/xfce-blue.jpg
/backdrop/screen0/monitor0/last-image  /usr/share/backgrounds/xfce/xfce-blue.jpg
/desktop-icons/icon-size               32

joe@Joe-Car-Laptop ~ $ stat /usr/share/backgrounds/xfce/xfce-blue.jpg
  File: ‘/usr/share/backgrounds/xfce/xfce-blue.jpg’
  Size: 152462      Blocks: 304        IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 804h/2052d  Inode: 2119315     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2015-06-13 22:36:50.177980900 +0100
Modify: 2015-06-13 22:36:50.177980900 +0100
Change: 2015-06-13 22:36:57.327980819 +0100
 Birth: -

joe@Joe-Car-Laptop ~ $ file !$
file /usr/share/backgrounds/xfce/xfce-blue.jpg
/usr/share/backgrounds/xfce/xfce-blue.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, resolution (DPI), density 150x150, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 1920x1200, frames 3, comment: "Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported (CC BY-SA 3.0)", baseline, precision 8, 1920x1200, frames 3, baseline, precision 8, 1920x1200, frames 3
```

If I open Settings Manager > Desktop > Add (+) > /usr/share/backgrounds/xfce there are no images listed (even though there is an image in this directory xfce-blue.jpg).

[image: screenshot]

How can I get my background image back?

As a side note: the background for `lightdm` is also not showing either (also set to `/usr/share/backgrounds/xfce-blue.jpg`).

Comment: How can I improve this question to get someone's input not this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this issue was caused by my `USE` flags being too restrictive in `make.conf`: I had `USE="-jpeg -png"`.

Once I removed the above USE flags and rebuilt all packages which needed rebuilding with `sudo emerge --update --newuse @world`, my desktop background can back after logging out and back in again.

Thanks to "iamben" in the #gentoo room on IRC for nudging me in the right direction on this one!